# `brew install cocoapods` fetch the latest ruby 3.2.1. how can I prevent it and lock Ruby 3.1 without ruby version managers?

Tags: ruby, cocoapods, homebrew

As you see `brew install cocoapods` download `ruby@3.2` but I need to use ruby@3.1!

[image]

Comment: What is the reason to not use a ruby version manager? This is the reason why there are ruby version managers in the first place.

Comment: I don't know if this is still the case, but some cocoapods plugins like repo-art didn't work correctly when using ruby version management software.

Comment: ```
brew install ruby@3.1 7 ;
brew install cocoapods --ignore-dependencies ;
ln -s /opt/homebrew/opt/ruby@3.1 /opt/homebrew/opt/ruby
````

I tried a dirty way to force use ruby 3.1 (and it appears to be functioning properly)

Answer (score 2):

If your ruby was installed via homebrew,`brew pin ruby` or the specific ruby formula you have installed should do the trick.

That said, homebrew doesn't do any testing of mix-and-match versions so it's possible you may run into other problems as a side effect of the change.

For things like ruby, postgres, and so on other tooling to manage versions may create fewer points of friction than homebrew.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I install ruby@3.1 with brew, pin the ruby, then install cocoapods with brew, still the latest ruby 3.2.1 is installed.